# how to change the configuration of a relationship just for an instance of the dbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core, and the relationships are configurated in the `OnModelCreating` method. The relationship that I have is this:

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.EntityParent)
    .WithMany(p => p.EntityCHild)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.IDEntityParent)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.restrict)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_Name");
```

And when I want to use EF Core I use this code:

```
using(Context myContext = new Context())
{
    //Code to use EF
}
```

But I would like to modify the relation between the two entities for a particular case, so I would like to change inside the using when I will go to use EF, not in the `OnModelCreating` method because if not I would modify for all instances of the `DbContext`.

I would like to change the behavior of `OnDeleting` from restrict to cascade.

My idea is this:

```
using(Context myContext = new Context())
{
    //Code to modify the behavior from restrict to cascade.


    //Code to use EF
}
```

Is it possible to do that? How I could do that if it is possible?

Comment: Delete behaviour is a property of database column (of foreign key), so you cannot do what you want, because modifying delete behavior requires modifying database column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use derived context...

```
 public class Context: DbContext{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         ...
         entity.HasOne(d => d.EntityParent)
           .WithMany(p => p.EntityCHild)
          .HasForeignKey(d => d.IDEntityParent)
          .OnDelete(ShouldRestrict)
          .HasConstraintName("FK_Name");
         ...
    }

    protected virtual DeleteBehavior ShouldRestrict{
        get{
            return DeleteBehavior.restrict;
        }
    }

 }


 public class UnrestrictedContext: Context{
    protected override DeleteBehavior ShouldRestrict{
        get{
            // change...
            return DeleteBehavior.....;
        }
    }
 }
```

So in exceptional case, you can use UnrestrictedContext instead of Context.